# When I try to add a gradient to my text it will only do so in black and white!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient, cs5

I have created a colour gradient I wish to use, but when I go to `Blending Options > Gradient Overlay` it applies the gradient but only in black and white (suddenly my colours are only grey/black/white.

I've checked the settings by going to `Image > Mode > RGB` and that is fine. I've also checked the colour settings under `Edit > Colour settings > SRGB` so I am at a loss as to why it keeps doing this.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: have you checked your layer blending mode properly?

Comment: Ensure you don't have a layer mask highlighted.

Comment: The blending mode should be set to normal and is found in a list at the top of your layers panel and contains terms like `Multiply`, `Subtract`, `Hard Light`, etc...

Comment: Hi Bart, yes thats set to normal.  Totally bizarre how it only changes the colour mode once I add the gradient layer.

Comment: Does this happen with any coloured gradient or just the one in particular that you want to use? If it's just your one perhaps the opacity settings for the gradient aren't high enough? Good luck with this, it's definitely a bizzarre one :)

Answer (score 2):

The default color for gradient is black and white.
Make sure that you didn't skip some steps and click ok button before color it.

[image: 3 Steps to make sure that you already color it.]

1. Start with Blending Option >> Gradient Overlay
2. Click the B/W gradient to change it.
3. Gradient Editor popup, you can change what color you want.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In the layer box, double click on the gradient overlay effect, next to the eyeball icon. There, you can customize your gradient. Same goes for any layer property. You can select the type of gradient (one color, two color, etc), and also the colors used in the gradient. I just figured this out last night!

Aaron